# What is the term for saying something like A is B,and B is A?

Tags: terminology

Watching an ad about a mobile network operator that recently changed it's brand name:
**Tunisiana is ooredooo, and ooredoo is Tunisiana**

is there a term for this kind of statement?
another example: 
**One for all, and all for one**

Comment: "Fair is foul, and foul is fair." (William Shakespeare, Macbeth I.i)

Comment: http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/chiasmusterm.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Chiasmus](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/chiasmusterm.htm) is the classical term for examples of 'cross-over phrasing'.

How 'classical'

> Nice to see you ... to see you, nice.

was is another matter.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, the statement "A is B and B is A" postulates an [equivalence](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/equivalence) of A and B, i.e. that they can be used [interchangeably](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/interchangeable) (as opposed to one being a subset of the other).

Comment: But that doesn't hold for the second example :)

Comment: Mathematically, the statement "A **R** B <=> B **R** A" defines merely the symmetry aspect of a possible equivalence relation on a set containing (general) elements A and B. The relation **R** can of course be 'equals' / 'is [the same as]'. "A is/equals B" is enough to specify an equivalence relation in this case. Reflexivity (eg, where the relation is 'equals', A = A) and transitivity (A = B and B = C => A = C) are also required properties.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth To me this type of sentence rather describes a reciprocity. You say A *R* B (`=>` ie. necessary condition) , but then also B *R* A (`<=` aka. satisfying condition).

Comment: @ Arlaud Pierre I'm sorry, **which** type of sentence? A symmetric relation, say ~, is one where if a ~ b then b ~ a for all a,b within the set / population. Obviously, 'is greater than' is not a symmetric relation (and hence not an equivalence relation), because a > b does not permit b > a. [But this is maths. I'm pointing out here that this answer is perhaps unhelpful. As does oerkelens. And 'reciprocity relation' has a different, defined meaning in calculus.]